# How to pass data with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components

How do i pass data from the controller to a component to show to the user?

app.js

```
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';
  angular.module('app', []).controller('MainCtrl', function MainCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/team',
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.teams = response.data;
      $scope.teams = response.data;
      // var keys = Object.keys($scope.agendaEventData);
      // $scope.eventslength = keys.length;
      
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
    });
      
  }).config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }]);
  })(window.angular);
```

component

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('app').component('bringTeamToEvent', {
  templateUrl: '/assets/ng/app/team/bringTeamToEvent.html',
  bindings: {
    teams: '<'
  },
  
});
})(window.angular);
```

Template

```
{{$ctrl.teams}}
{{teams}}
```

The data is coming from the api no problems, i do not understand the complexity to get it to work.
Learning from https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_13
and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the data on `this.teams` is correct, and correct to access it like `$ctrl.teams`.  The issue here is that your `$http` callback functions are injecting their own function context so that `this` doesn't refer to the component.

For this reason, it's generally good practice to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for callback functions:

```js
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/team',
}).then(response => {
  this.teams = response.data;
}, response => {
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/rfxobdhv/)